# Which is better? Passing parameters from controller or using uri?

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

I need to make a dynamic page that is something like : `example.com/nameofbook/1` - where 1 is the number of the page.

This are 2 parameters.

I know 2 ways of doing it. 
1. In controller I have function page($book, $page) 
2. Take from the link the parameters with this->uri->segment.

What should I use and why and which one is safer?

Anyhow when I use the controller with 2 parameters the CSS code doesn't load. When I use 1 it loads.
my route is something like `$route['page/(:any)/(:any)']='main/page/$1/$2'`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: note that you also could do it with a form so you are not exposing anything - just pass the book name and page number as hidden form fields and instead of a next page link you have a button or graphic. but either way make sure you are cleaning/validating that data before sending it to your database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the $this->uri->segment is exactly the same as using parameters in the controller.. the parameters will get passed to the controller if its part of the URI whether you have defined them in the method or not.

i.e:

```
page() {
    // This will be an array of passed arguments
    $args = func_get_args();
}
```

I am not sure why your CSS doesn't load with one method over another.
also judging by your URI, your route won't work.. because the 'page' part is not in the URI, so your URI should be `example.com/page/nameofbook/1`

either way is 'safe' it makes no difference in the 2 ways you suggest.

Comment: well, i don't understand how the route should look. i have $route['nameofbook/(:any)'] = 'main/nameofbook/$1'; which works

Comment: If you don't want page to be in your URI, then you will have to setup a route for every single `nameofbook` possible.. so it will look like: `$route['nameofbook1/(:num)'] = 'main/page/nameofbook1/$1'; $route['nameofbook2/(:num)'] = 'main/page/nameofbook2/$1'; etc...`